# Is Ubuntu also available in Latin language?

Tags: language-support, system-language

This sounds like a fun question, but as somebody who currently learns Latin asked me that, maybe there is indeed a Latin language pack for Ubuntu?

That is, all system UI elements and also to possible extent applications should be displayed in Latin.

Comment: done... hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

No. The Latin language [exists in Launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+lang/la), but far too few strings have been translated yet to motivate the creation of Latin language packs.

You may want to join the [Decuria latinitatis team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-la) and help with the translation into Latin.